VS Code and Python: move directory refactor
When I move a .py file in VS Code, the Python extension automatically triggers a refactor, editing imports throughout the project. But it doesn't trigger if I move the entire directory with the .py files.
I've been able to move the entire directory correctly only by dragging and dropping files one by one, or by text replacement of imports across the entire project.
Refactor triggers only if you drag and drop only one file. In addition, there may be subdirectories.
Is there any way to refactor the imports when moving the whole directory, just like for a single .py file?
